# How to add leverage browser caching to my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to add leverage browser caching in my worspress site. 
I have added code in my `.htaccess` file below:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

But i am not able to solve it.
Please help me to sove it.

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct to me, although I normally do it like this:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A60
# Font files expire in 1 year
ExpiresByType font/otf A31449600
ExpiresByType font/x-woff A31449600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31449600
ExpiresByType font/ttf A31449600
# Image files expire in 1 month
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
# Stylesheet & Javascript files expire in 1 week
ExpiresByType text/css A604800
ExpiresByType text/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType application/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A604800
# HTML files do not expire
ExpiresByType text/html A0
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml A0
</ifModule>
```

Are you sure your host supports the "mod_expires" module?

Comment: i am using IIS server.is it support "mod_expires" mudule?how can i check it?